# asp.net pages randomly lose all form data and do not postback

Tags: asp.net

we've had a production application in use for about 7 years, and recently it started some strange behavior. There are a few pages where, when a user clicks a button that causes a postback and some proecessing, the browser looks like it's doing something (that is, the processing icon starts churning), but then it stops and all form data that the user enters disappears. The request never makes it to the server - I see no trace of it in the IIS logs.. no error gets written to the event log, and there are no javascript errors. It just starts and then stops. It only happens to certain users and it's not repeatable... the same user can use the same page again and it works and fails randomly. I can't reproduce the error. The browser being used is the latest Internet Explorer. I am a seasoned asp.net developer and have never seen this before.. I never ask a question in here, but this time i'm completely stumped because there is no trace of anything happening so I can't debug. Has anybody seen anything like this before?

Comment: "the same user can use the same page again and it works" does that mean that when user refresh the page it start working? Do you have a screenshot representing that weird state? One reason could be that due to excessive javascript execution the browser gets stuck.

Comment: I mean that it happens randomly... there is no sequence of user actions which consistently causes it. The same user can do the exact same thing on different days and it happens on one day, not the other... refreshing the page doesn't necessarily fix it. It makes me think it has something to do with maybe the server... maybe the load fluctuating and causing requests to not be responded to.. but I don't know.